# Two controllers with same name under different packages in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two controller classes with the same name but in different packages under my Spring MVC application but when compiling the application refuses to run on server giving me an error.

Any chance anyone knows how to allow having same controller class name in two (different packages) under a Spring MVC project?

Comment: Post the error!!!
You can define two controllers with same name in different packages. But the request mapping should be differenet.

Comment: nothing wrong with using two controllers with same name in two packages , just package should be imported , plz post the error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use value attribute of controller annotation

```
@Controller("controller1")
```

and

```
@Controller("controller2")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the professional and correct answer. Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Bassem's answer,

If you had two controllers in 2 packages:

- pkg1

  - myController
- pkg2

  - myController

You could use the `@Controller` annotation:

```
@Controller("pkg1 myController")
@Controller("pkg2 myController")
```

So that way it is more organized. You also cannot have the same value in your `@Controller("THIS VALUE")`.

So if you had:

pkg1
 - myController1
 - myController2

You can not have them both have 
`@Controller("pkg1")`

Instead you could use `@Controller("pkg1 myController1)` to avoid collisions